# how to redirect from Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST to index.html

Tags: asp.net, shibboleth, saml-2.0

I have Configured Service Provider on my server(iis), it seems everything works fine. Login good. SAML encoding fine. 
But it redirect me to "**https://example.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST**"
and i want to go to "**https://example.com/secure/index.html**"

Below are my Configuration

```
<SPConfig xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config"
xmlns:conf="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config"
xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
clockSkew="180">

<InProcess logger="native.logger">
    <ISAPI normalizeRequest="true" safeHeaderNames="true">
        <Site id="1" name="mydomain.com"  scheme="https" port="443"/>
    </ISAPI>
</InProcess>
<RequestMapper type="Native">
    <RequestMap>
        <Host name="mydomain.com">
            <Path name="secure" authType="shibboleth" equireSession="true"/>
        </Host>
    </RequestMap>
</RequestMapper>
<ApplicationDefaults entityID="https://www.example.com/shibboleth" 
                     homeURL="https://example.com/secure/index.html"
                     REMOTE_USER="eppn persistent-id targeted-id">      
    <Sessions lifetime="28800" timeout="3600" relayState="ss:mem"
              handlerURL="/Shibboleth.sso" handlerSSL="false"
        exportLocation="http://example.com/Shibboleth.sso/GetAssertion"
              checkAddress="false" cookieProps="https">
        <SSO entityID="https://test-idp.ukfederation.org.uk/idp/shibboleth" discoveryProtocol="WAYF" discoveryURL="https://wayf.ukfederation.org.uk/WAYF">
            SAML2 SAML1
        </SSO>
        <Logout>SAML2 Local</Logout>
        <Handler type="MetadataGenerator" Location="/Metadata" signing="false"/>
        <Handler type="Status" Location="/Status" acl="127.0.0.1 ::1"/>
        <Handler type="Session" Location="/Session" showAttributeValues="false"/>
        <Handler type="DiscoveryFeed" Location="/DiscoFeed"/>
        <Handler type="AttributeChecker" Location="/AttrChecker" template="attrChecker.html"
            attributes="eppn" flushSession="true"/>
    </Sessions>
    <Errors supportContact="support@mydomain.com"
       helpLocation="/about.html"
       styleSheet="/shibboleth-sp/main.css"/>       

    <MetadataProvider type="XML" uri="http://metadata.ukfederation.org.uk/ukfederation-metadata.xml"
                  backingFilePath="ukfederation-metadata.xml" reloadInterval="14400">
        <MetadataFilter type="RequireValidUntil" maxValidityInterval="2592000"/>
        <MetadataFilter type="Signature" certificate="ukfederation.crt"/>
    </MetadataProvider>
    <AttributeExtractor type="XML" validate="true" reloadChanges="false" path="attribute-map.xml"/>
    <AttributeResolver type="Query" subjectMatch="true"/>
    <AttributeFilter type="XML" validate="true" path="attribute-policy.xml"/>
    <CredentialResolver type="File" key="sp-key.pem" certificate="sp-cert.pem"/>
</ApplicationDefaults>
<SecurityPolicyProvider type="XML" validate="true" path="security-policy.xml"/>
<ProtocolProvider type="XML" validate="true" reloadChanges="false" path="protocols.xml"/>
```

Comment: It _should_ do that automatically as a next step after the POST-Request succeeded.

Comment: What message do you get at that page?

Comment: 500.21 error page, "ManagedPipelineHandler"